# issues when using pycassa with uwsgi

Tags: python, cassandra, connection-pooling, uwsgi, pycassa

We are using pycassa with uwsgi. There are about 16 uwsgi processes.

It is strange that one process can get the data which is queried by
another process. e.g. there is one row in column family A, looks like:

{row_key, {'column_a': 1, 'column_b': 2}}

process 1 run: get(row_key, columns=['column_a', ])

process 2 run: get(row_key, columns=['column_b', ])

but, sometimes, process 1 got value of column_b, process 2 got value
of column_a.

Is this a known issue of connection pool?

Any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a connection for every worker using the uwsgi.post_fork_hook api function

```
import uwsgi

def myconnect(...):

global_connection = ...

uwsgi.post_fork_hook = myconnect
```

Comment: >>> import uwsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named uwsgi
Is uwsgi module for python needed?

Comment: when you run an app under uwsgi it get access to the uwsgi module.

Comment: And I add a judgement, "if not global_connection: global_connection = ..." in case a worker is restarted.